# Using Sun Editor in Next JS with CodeMirror

Tags: next.js, codemirror, suneditor

I am trying to use SunEditor in a NextJS app which I am able to with dynamic imports as below

```
const SunEditor = dynamic(() => import("suneditor-react"), {
  ssr: false,
});
```

Now the problem begins when I wish to use the codeMirror option in the Editor which turns out I need to import dynamically as well

```
const CodeMirror = dynamic(() => import("codemirror"), {
  ssr: false,
});
```

And after setting the codeMirror option correctly this error occurs

```
TypeError: options.codeMirror.src.fromTextArea is not a function
```

Has anyone been able to use it NextJS. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you used typescript ?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?